# Script to Download Facebook Album

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to learn about JavaScript by coding a Facebook album downloader that I can run. For example, I want it to download all the photos from this album: https://www.facebook.com/pg/FacebookUK/photos/?tab=album&album_id=473083416653&ref=page_internal.

I have code that is close to working, except the rel=theater attribute for the `<a>` tag seems to be messing up the download-on-click feature I was relying on. I tried deleting this attribute, but it does not seem to successfully delete. Here's what my script looks like:

```
var album = document.getElementsByClassName("_2eea");
var n = album.length;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var image = album[i];
    image = image.children[0];
    image.setAttribute('download', i.toString().concat(".jpg") );
    image.setAttribute('href', image.children[0].getAttribute("src") )
    image.click();
}
```

The theater display opens upon "click"-ing, then hangs. I don't know how to suppress this. Alternatively, if there's a better strategy for coding this downloader, please let me know!

Comment: [Chrome v 65+ will block cross-origin <a download>](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations#block_cross-origin_wzxhzdk5a_download). This could be your issue since facebook hosts it's images on a CDN (fbcdn.net)

Comment: @frobinsonj oh I see. Is there a workaround method for an implementation? I feel there should be a way to automate this process since I can do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to get each image as a blob. You can then use [`window.URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create a URL representing the object given. Then, add this URL to an a tag and add the download attributes.

```js
function getBlob(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(function(response) { return response.blob(); })
}

const album = document.getElementsByClassName("_2eea");
const n = album.length;
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const image = album[i].children[0].children[0];
    getBlob(image.src).then(function(blob) {
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = i + "." + blob.type.slice(6);
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    });
}
```